# Wie sagt man “according to”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, expression

Recently, I wanted to say something like:

> According to the national emergency office …

but I didn’t find an expression for *according to*.

It seems to me that the translation *nach* refers to a place a person is going *towards*; like the Spanish *hacia*. This is why I ask, because maybe Germans say it differently?

So what would be an idiomatic expression?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please specify what you found in a dictionary and why it did not satisfy you? Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed. See [How do I ask good, on-topic questions for translations or about differences?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628/2594).

Comment: It seems to me that the translation "nach" is refered to a place a person can, is, will, would, have, go/going/go/go/gone, like the word "towards" in English or "hacia" in Spanish. This is why I asked, because maybe Germans say it differently.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: The preposition "nach" has several meanings and uses. The one referring to a place someone's going to is just one of them. The one meaning "according to" is another one.

Comment: Considering that the answers show that using a dictionary can also lead a native speaker to a wrong answer, I do not understand why this was closed.

Comment: See Linguee  http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=englisch&query=according+to or Leo  http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=according%20to&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on    You have to learn which dictionary gives what information. Don't use only one dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends a bit on the exact context; in your example *laut* is the best option:

> Laut Nationaler Notfallbehörde ...

*Gemäß* sounds okay, too. Or you could say:

> Der Nationalen Notfallbehörde zufolge ...

Answer (score 5):

### »Entsprechend«, »gemäß«, »laut«

> **According to** the national emergency office...
> **Laut dem** nationalen Notfallbüro ...

Beachte, dass im Englischen nach »according« immer die Präposition »to« verwendet wird, die im Deutschen meist mit »zu« übersetzt wird, während das bei den deutschen Entsprechungen nicht der Fall ist.

*Entsprechend*, *gemäß* und *laut* verlangen den Dativ ohne dazwischengeschobene Präposition.

> Seine Bewegung wurde, den Basketball-Regeln **entsprechend**, als Foul behandelt.
> His move was treated as a foul, **according** to the rules of basketball.
>
> **Gemäß** Hausordnung sind Hunde hier nicht erlaubt.
> Dogs are not allowed here, **according** to the house rules.

Comment: „Entsprechend“ halte ich hier für falsch. Bei „gemäß“ bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Comment: @CarstenS: Ich habe meine Antwort um zwei Beispiele ergänzt, um »entsprechend« und »gemäß« als korrekte Übersetzung von »according« zu belegen.

Comment: _according to_ kann sich auf eine (oft juristische) Person beziehen, die konkret etwas gesagt hat, oder auf einen Text (Regeln etc.), der etwas abstrakt besagt. _gemäß_ und _entsprechend_ sollte man nur für zweiteres verwenden.

Answer (score 1):

> **In Übereinstimmung mit** dem nationalen Notfallbüro...

... in addition to the other suggestions.

Comment: My suggesion is absolutely acceptable: http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=according%20to&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on

Comment: I think that "according to the NEO, X" simply means "the NEO says X". While "In Übereinstimmung mit" suggests that we, or someone, agrees with what the NEO says.